# Mail merge Data populate on radRichtextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I need quick support to populate mail merge data on radrichtextbox. In the first step, i simply populate list of data in Mail merge like "FirstName", "LastName", then i want to get data associated with these tags e.g Firstname=Peter ....Please also take a look of below lines of code. My question is how can I load the FirstName, LastName data on document when press Preview Results.

**on Load**

```
this.radRichTextBox.Document.MailMergeDataSource.ItemsSource = new List<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee()
                {
                    FirstName = "Guest1",
                    LastName = "Guest2",  
                },
                new Employee()
                {
                    FirstName = "Ali",
                    LastName = "Doc", 
                }
            };

private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           //this.radRichTextBox.InsertField(new MergeField() { PropertyPath = "FirstName" });
           MergeField field = new MergeField() { PropertyPath = "FirstName" };
           field.DisplayMode = FieldDisplayMode.Result;
           this.radRichTextBox.Document.ChangeFieldDisplayMode(field.FieldStart, FieldDisplayMode.Result);
    }
```

Comment: And your question is? What's the issue?

Comment: my question is I can not load the FirstName, LastName data on document when press Preview Results.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a merge field in RadRichTextBox's RadDocument using the InsertField method of RadRichTextBox:

```
this.radRichTextBox.InsertField(new MergeField() { PropertyPath = "FirstName" }, FieldDisplayMode.Result);
```

Note that the display mode is set to `FieldDisplayMode.Result` during the insertion, this will ensure that the field will be evaluated immediately using the data source.

The fields in RadRichTextBox have three display modes: `Code`, `DisplayName` and `Result`. If you have inserted the fields in `Code` or `DisplayName` modes, you can change the mode of all fields in the document at later time (after the insert) using the following:

```
this.radRichTextBox.ChangeAllFieldsDisplayMode(FieldDisplayMode.Result);
```